# How to count the number of two observations binary combinations?

Tags: r, count

In the example below, I would like the know the number of `010` sequences, or the number of `1010` sequences.  Below is a workable example;

```
x <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
```

In this example, the number of `010` sequences would be 6 and the number of `1010` sequences would be 4.

What would be the most efficient/simplest way to count the number of consecutive sequences?

Comment: This works for the first case `sum(diff(diff(x)) == -2)` but someone can check where if it fails anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution would be this:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
xx = paste0(x, collapse = "")
str_count(xx, '(?<=010)')
[1] 6

str_count(xx, '(?<=1010)')
[1] 4
```

As @Pierre Lafortune pointed out in the comments this can be done without using any packages:

```
length(gregexpr("(?<=010)", xx, perl=TRUE)[[1]])
[1] 6
```

Comment: hey this is cool!! i need to learn this package very soon i guess!! :) I was busy trying using base R

Comment: @joel.wilson it's really convenient for counting things like this.

Comment: Yes the output is incorrect in both cases.  I think the codes are rolling forward and not taking account of all the observations.  For instance for "1010" the answer should be 4.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Excellent except the second one ("1010") has an extra ' it doesn't need

Comment: No need for the complicated set up `length(gregexpr("(?<=010)", xx, perl=TRUE)[[1]])`

Comment: Nor are any packages necessary.

Comment: @Andrew Fixed that now too. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

A stringless way:

```
f = function(x, patt){
  if (length(x) == length(patt)) return(as.integer(x == patt))
  w = head(seq_along(x), 1L-length(patt))
  for (k in seq_along(patt)) w <- w[ x[w + k - 1L] == patt[k] ]
  w
}

length(f(x, patt = c(0,1,0))) # 6
length(f(x, patt = c(1,0,1,0))) # 4
```

---

**Alternatives.** From @cryo11, here's another way:

```
function(x,patt) sum(apply(embed(x,length(patt)),1,function(x) all(!xor(x,patt))))
```

or another variation:

```
function(x,patt) sum(!colSums( xor(patt, t(embed(x,length(patt)))) ))
```

or with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(shift(x, seq_along(patt), type = "lead")))[as.list(patt), .N]
```

(The `shift` function is very similar to `embed`.)

Comment: +1 for the "stringless" way. Here another one: `f=function(x,patt) sum(apply(embed(x,length(patt)),1,function(x) all(!xor(x,patt))))`. This one does not need an outer `length`.

Comment: @cryo111 Cool, never thought of using xor for that! I guess there are also ways to use the `embed` with `==`, transpose/sweep, and col or row sums.

Answer (score 5):

logic : take a substr of length of pattern you are searching for and compare it with the pattern.

```
xx = paste0(x, collapse = "")
# [1] "1001000111001010101010"
# case 1 :
xxx = "010"
sum(sapply(1:(length(x)-nchar(xxx)+1), function(i) substr(xx,i,i+nchar(xxx)-1)==xxx))
# [1] 6

# case 2 :
xxx = "1010"
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 3):

R introduced the `startsWith` function in 3.3.0. Using this and `substring`, we can implement @joel.wilson's method as

```
sum(startsWith(substring(paste(x, collapse=""),
                         head(seq_along(x), -2), tail(seq_along(x), -2)), "010"))
```

Here, `substring` constructs all three character adjacent sets and `startsWith` tests if each of these is the same as "010". The TRUE values are then summed together.